# jQuery Function Seems to Quit When Different jQuery Function Is Called

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I wrote my own function that keeps a sidebar fixed on screen after a certain point of scrolling and then returns it to it's relative position when scrolled back to the top. If the window is resized to a size smaller then the height of the sidebar, it returns it to its normal relative position as well. Works great!

Problem is when I run another function, namely fancybox(), on the panoramic thumbnail in the body of the page, and try scrolling, my original "scroll-fix" function seems to stop working.

Anyone know why this is?

////////////////////
**[Demo Page](http://nectar.myshopify.com/pages/our-story)**

////////////////////

////////////////////////////////////
**"Scroll-Fix" Function**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

  var element = $("#sidebar");
  var window_height = $(window).height();
  var element_height = element.height();

  $(window).ready(function() { 
    if (window_height > element_height) {
      if (($(document).scrollTop() + element.height()) > ($(document).height() - $("#footer").height() - 9)) {
        element.css("position","absolute");
        element.css("top", "auto");
        element.css("bottom","-60px");
      }
      else if ($(document).scrollTop() > 220) {
        element.css("position","fixed");
        element.css("top","9px");
        element.css("padding-top","0");
        element.css("bottom","auto");
      }
      else {
        element.css("position","relative");
        element.css("top","auto");
        element.css("padding-top","57px");
        element.css("bottom","auto");    
      }
    }
    else {
      element.css("position","relative");
      element.css("top","auto");
      element.css("padding-top","57px");
        element.css("bottom","auto");
    }
  });


  $(window).scroll(function() { 
    if (window_height > element_height) {
      if (($(document).scrollTop() + element.height()) > ($(document).height() - $("#footer").height() - 9)) {
        element.css("position","absolute");
        element.css("top", "auto");
        element.css("bottom","-60px");
      }
      else if ($(document).scrollTop() > 220) {
        element.css("position","fixed");
        element.css("top","9px");
        element.css("padding-top","0");
        element.css("bottom","auto");
      }
      else {
        element.css("position","relative");
        element.css("top","auto");
        element.css("padding-top","57px");
        element.css("bottom","auto");    
      }
    }
    else {
      element.css("position","relative");
      element.css("top","auto");
      element.css("padding-top","57px");
        element.css("bottom","auto");
    }
  });

  $(window).resize(function(){
    window_height = $(window).height();
    if (window_height > element_height) {
      if (($(document).scrollTop() + element.height()) > ($(document).height() - $("#footer").height() - 9)) {
        element.css("position","absolute");
        element.css("top", "auto");
        element.css("bottom","-60px");
      }
      else if ($(document).scrollTop() > 220) {
        element.css("position","fixed");
        element.css("top","9px");
        element.css("padding-top","0");
        element.css("bottom","auto");
      }
      else {
        element.css("position","relative");
        element.css("top","auto");
        element.css("padding-top","57px"); 
        element.css("bottom","auto");     
      }
    }
    else {
      element.css("position","relative");
      element.css("top","auto");
      element.css("padding-top","57px");
        element.css("bottom","auto");
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Nice design and chick on the webpage! I couldn't experience your problem though, with Google Chrome.

Comment: Sorry, noticed it now. I'd rather have a look at what fancybox is doing that makes your script break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first changes for this code to not generate the same problems

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myScrollFix = function(options) {

        options = $.extend({
            footer:  "footer",
            pthis: this,
            doc: $(document),
            win: $(window)
        }, options || {});

        options.footer = $(options.footer);
        options.accion = function() {

            var element = options.pthis,
                doc_scroll_top = options.doc.scrollTop(),
                doc_height  = options.doc.height(),
                window_height = options.win.height(),
                element_height = options.pthis.height(),
                footer_height = options.footer.height();

            if (window_height > element_height) {
                if ((doc_scroll_top + element_height) > (doc_height - footer_height - 9)) {
                    element
                        .css("position","absolute")
                        .css("top", "auto")
                        .css("bottom","-60px");
                }
                else if (doc_scroll_top > 220) {
                    element
                        .css("position","fixed")
                        .css("top","9px")
                        .css("padding-top","0")
                        .css("bottom","auto");
                }
                else {
                    element
                        .css("position","relative")
                        .css("top","auto")
                        .css("padding-top","57px")
                        .css("bottom","auto");    
                }
            }
            else {
                element
                    .css("position","relative")
                    .css("top","auto")
                    .css("padding-top","57px")
                    .css("bottom","auto");
            }
        };

        $(window).bind("scroll", options.accion);
        $(window).bind("resize", options.accion);

        options.accion();
    };
})(jQuery);
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sidebar").myScrollFix();
});
```

then you can modify these lines in FancyBox

line 432

```
$(window).unbind("resize scroll", $.fn.fancybox.scrollBox);
```

line 439

```
$(window).unbind("resize scroll", $.fn.fancybox.scrollBox);
```

Comment: Wow, I cannot thank you enough!  The only thing I noticed that I had to change was when you were defining the footer variable. It's "#footer" not "footer.  I make that mistake ALL the time.

You wouldn't happen to want to take a stab at my other JS issue!?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400646/calling-jqzoom-on-replaceable-image

Answer (score 3):

I had a very similar problem and I tried commenting it and it worked but after that I tried another solution and it worked too. Basically, I targeted the actual element that the close scroll was needed for only which in my case was prettyPhoto

```
$(window).unbind('scroll', $.prettyPhoto.close);
```

The bold part **, $.prettyPhoto.close** is what I added.

I hope this helps anyone who ran into this scroll close problem with prettyPhoto.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Solved.**

Turns out FancyBox.js has a line that basically says, *when you close the fancy box...*

```
if (opts.centerOnScroll) {
  $(window).unbind("resize scroll");
}
```

Unbinding the window causes my scroll-fix solution to unbind as well.

A simple commenting-out of that line (which occurs twice in that fancybox close function) fixes this problem.

```
if (opts.centerOnScroll) {
//  $(window).unbind("resize scroll");
}
```